# how to filter a MVC SelectList to remove unwanted values

Tags: c#, .net

I have a SelectList and I need to filter out when the Text value is emptyOrNull?  I'm struggling to get this working.  Any ideas?  I've tried this

**Example code**

```
// My list - this is valid code
SelectList list = model.MySelectList;  

// But when I try this I get the following error message?
SelectList test = list.Where(x => x.Text != "");
```

I receive the following compiler error message

**Error**

```
Error convert source .. IEnumerable<SelectListItem> to target type SelectList
```

**UPDATE - I need to filter out values, i.e. I need something like**

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text))
    {
        // remove item from list
    }
}

// Then list does not include any items with a Value which is null or empty
```

**UPDATE**

After making the following change, the code compiles but I get 'Select.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' in the rendered dropdown.

```
new SelectList(list.Where(x => x.Text != ""));
```

Please advise, many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways,

(i). Getting only the values which are not null or not empty using LINQ

```
List<SelectListItem> test = list.Where(item => item.Text != null || !(item.Text.Equals(string.Empty))).ToList();
```

(ii).Second way is to find the values and remove from the original

```
List<SelectListItem> filedNullOrEmpty = list.Where(item => item.Text == null ||     item.Text.Equals(string.Empty)).ToList();
  foreach (Select selobj in filedNullOrEmpty)
  {
   list.Remove(selobj);
  }
```

Comment: thank you, this returns the item but how can I filter our these items?  Thanks,

Comment: @user3773890 Check the modified answer

Comment: thanks - I get Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Comment: "List<SelectListItem> test = list" change it like thsi

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Where` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, not `SelectList` - try using this [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492864%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
SelectList test = new SelectList(list.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happened because .Where() returns IEnumerable. You should convert to SeletList type.

One of option is `.Where(x => x.Text != "").Select(new SelectListItem(){Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value});`

Answer (score 0):

The SelectList constructor takes an IEnumerable so all you need to do is pass the LINQ query to the constructor like so

```
  var query = from c in source
              where c.Key != ""
              select c;

 var customerList = new SelectList(query, "DataTextField", "DataValueField");
```

Wish I could help you.

Comment: Thanks but I get a runtime error: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'DataTextField'.

Comment: "DataTextField" is your dynamic string like the Key of your binding selectlist item, and so is the string of "DataValueField".